# Fill rectangle with temporary window

Tags: windows, temporary

I have a bedroom that has a rectangular space that I would like to fill in with a temporary (hopefully easy to install) window. Any ideas? Here is a picture:
[image]

Comment: Buy a window from a local dealer and install it.

Comment: Temporary you say, use acrylic glass

Comment: For temporary indoor use, a piece of plexiglass cut to fit the opening and wood moulding or similar like quarter round or cove to act like a window frame to hold the plexiglass in place.

Comment: What's the purpose of wanting a window there?  The answer might determine what sort of covering is needed.  Noise, light, air movement, security, etc.?

Comment: https://www.homedepot.com/b/Home-Decor-Wall-Decor-Stained-Glass-Panels/N-5yc1vZc2ob/Ntk-elasticplus/Ntt-stained+glass?Ntx=mode+matchpartialmax&NCNI-5&visNavSearch=stained%20glass

Comment: Looking to maintain air flow and decrease noise from leaving and entering!

Comment: What kind of sealant cant I get so it's secure but easy to remove?

Comment: Won't putting a window there *eliminate* air flow?  As to sealant, if you want to do that you could just use some acrylic caulk.  You'd want to get the plexi pane cut pretty close to the size of the opening.